# Roboto inconsistent font height

Tags: android, font-size

I'm currently facing strange problems with Android's font Roboto. At first I had two TextViews in one horizontal LinearLayout, centered both vertically and horizontally. The first TextView was set font Roboto-Black.ttf and the second was Roboto-Light.ttf. Both was set to textSize="12sp", but the one with Roboto-Light.ttf was just a pixel higher then the Roboto-Black.ttf TextView. But it didn't happen when I've set textSize="13sp". So I've created new Android project, just to be sure it's not only in the one application. The result is almost identical, but in this case, textSize="12sp" works as expected but textSize="13sp" doesn't. I've made screenshots to show the issue.

12sp works as expected. Top edges align.
[image]

13sp has this strange behavior.
[image]

Strange is, that this happens only when I try to mix thin and thick lined variants. When I make one TextView Roboto-Bold.ttf and second Roboto-Black.ttf, result is good. When I try Roboto-Light.ttf and Roboto-Thin.ttf, it also work properly.

So I also tried to test this in photoshop and this is what I found:

[image]

It's the same for all fonts from Roboto family, except for the Roboto-Light.ttf. I can also post source code for the layout if needed.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm sorry for the links but due to low reputation (brand new account) I can't post images. Also in the last link i had to remove the "h" from "http", because it didn't allow me more than two links.

Comment: I guess there is nothing you can do about that but try to play with the sizes and use like 12.9sp for the bigger one.

Comment: Thanks for the images. Anyway, this isn't the best approach as I can't predict how it will behave when those SP are calculated to pixels. I tried 18 and 19 pixels for the textSize (on my hdpi device it's equal to 12sp) and I got the same, wrong result. My point is that on smaller (or larger) screens there might be the same issue even if I'll use 12.9sp for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you if its the fonts or how your phone interprets the fonts and displays them on the screen but I can tell you that I've had issues with centering views in the middle before.

Have you tried using a relativelayout and then align the second textviews top and bot with the first textview? That might solve the problem.

Comment: Good idea, I'll definitely try that and get back with results.

Comment: Thank you! I made them into `RelativeLayout` with `android:gravity="center"`, then made the one on right side align on top and bottom. One more thing above your solution was, I had to set `android:gravity="bottom"` to both TextViews. Thanks for your help.